# Which of the two algorithms:fl(a+b+c+d) or fl(d+c+b+a), computes more accurate result(with smaller absolute error)?

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-arithmetic

It is known that if a and b have an exact representation in given t-bit arithmetic, then fl(a+b) = (a+b)(1 +$\delta$), where fl() denotes the result of an operation performed by a computer, and |$\delta$| $\leqslant$ u and $u = 2^{-t-1}$ denotes the unit round-off error.

Assume $0 < a < b < c < d$ have exact representation. Which of the following two algorithms $fl(a+b+c+d)$ or $fl(d+c+b+a)$, computes more accurate result(with smaller absolute error)?

I understood the solution up to expansion $fl(a+b+c+d) $ to $a+b+c+d +(a+b)(\delta_1+\delta_1\delta_3 + \delta_1\delta_2 + \delta_1\delta_2\delta_3) + (a+b+c)(\delta_2+ \delta_2+\delta_3) + (a+b+c+d)\delta_3$

In the next step, it goes
$$fl(a+b+c+d)  \\= a+b+c+d +(a+b)(\delta_1+\delta_1\delta_3 + \delta_1\delta_2 + \delta_1\delta_2\delta_3) + (a+b+c)(\delta_2+ \delta_2+\delta_3) + (a+b+c+d)\delta_3 \\= a+b+c+d+(3a+3b+3c+3d)\delta$$

If someone could help me understand the steps involving this operation I would be grateful.
Thanks to everyone who take their time to help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Here is an illustration: assume $d=1$, and $a,b,c$ are just below epsmach, so that $fl(d+a)=a$, $fl(d+b)=b$, $fl(d+c)=c$, but $fl(a+b+c)$ is above epsmach. What happens then? Which of $fl(a+b+c+d)$ and $fl(d+c+b+a)$ is more accurate? By the way, floating point addition is not associative, so you have to be careful when writing  $fl(a+b+c+d)$: is it $fl(((a+b)+c)+d)$ or $fl(a+(b+(c+d)))$ or something else?